# Copy 2 lines from many into a new file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains randomly generated data like this:

```
AllocatedStorage     : 5
InstanceName         : testdatabase
SnapshotName         : testdatabase-05-07-15-00-00
CreateTime           : 05/07/2015 00:00:00 AM

AllocatedStorage     : 10
InstanceName         : testdb
SnapshotName         : testdb-10-07-15-00-00
CreateTime           : 10/07/2015 00:00:00 AM
```

I want to write both the snapshotname as well as createtime to be written to another file, of all the entries of this file like this:

```
SnapshotName         : testdatabase-05-07-15-00-00
CreateTime           : 05/07/2015 00:00:00 AM
SnapshotName         : testdb-10-07-15-00-00
CreateTime           : 10/07/2015 00:00:00 AM
```

I am able to write snapshotname of all the entries, but not createtime. What I've tried so far is:

```
Get-Content "path\file.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -match 'SnapshotName'} | Set-Content "path\file2.txt"
```

I tried like adding another Where-Object to the above code like this, but failed to achieve the target.

```
Get-Content "path\file.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -match 'SnapshotName'} | Where-Object {$_ -match 'CreateTime'} | Set-Content "path\file2.txt"
```

I know I am missing something small. Can someone please help me how can I achieve what I said above.? Any response would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's less code with `select-string`:

```
get-content "path\file.txt" | Select-String "^(SnapshotName|CreateTime)" | out-file "path\file2.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first Where-Object {$_ -match 'SnapshotName'} you only get lines with SnapshotName so you cannot use another Where-Object because it will search you previous output. Use this code:

```
Get-Content "path\file.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match 'SnapshotName' -or $_ -match 'CreateTime' } | Set-Content "path\file2.txt"
```

Comment: Same thing I tried with -and instead of -or. It didnt worked. So, do you think it will work.?

Comment: Instead of asking if this will work, just try it ;) Besides, you use '-and'? How One line from you document can be 'SnapshotName' and 'CreateTime' at the same time/simultaneously? Please read about pipeline, output and logical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an an other approach using a `switch` statement and regex

```
gc c:\temp\file.txt |%{                                                
    switch -regex ($_){                                                    
        '(SnapshotName.*)' {$Matches[1] |out-file c:\temp\resu.txt -append}    
        '(CreateTime.*)'{$Matches[1] |out-file c:\temp\resu.txt -append}       
    }                                                                                                                                             
}
```